# XML Error handler

Tags: xml, vba, user-interface, ms-word

Using the Custom UI Editor I created the following code which works perfectly.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<contextMenus>
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuText">
<!-- Add a commandbar button before "Cut" (at the top) -->
<dynamicMenu id="SSYLingo" insertBeforeMso="Cut"
getVisible="GetMenuVisible" 
getLabel="GetMenuLabel"
getImage="GetMenuIcon"
getContent="SetSSYLingo" />
<!-- Add a separator before "Cut" (below SSYLingo) -->
<menuSeparator id="SSYSeptor" insertBeforeMso="Cut" />
</contextMenu>
</contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

I need it NOT to run, or at least not to crash out, when any of the get-procedures aren't available. The code is embedded in a Word 2010 template. The get-procedures aren't available while Word is in Design mode, and I should like to suppress the resulting error messages.
I realise that this is probably a question solved easily by someone who knows the language. I don't. I am programming VBA and would appreciate some help with the XML here.